# Kadosh-status of fruit grown during shmita but picked afterwards?

Tags: halacha, shmita

If a fruit that has grown on a tree during the shmita year and is only picked in the 8th year (not a shmita year) does it have a kadosh (holy) status since it grew and was ready to be eaten during shmita?

Comment: Is the fruit an Etrog?

Comment: What difference would that make?

Comment: Whether or not it is Kadosh.

Comment: Please clarify what you are insinuating?? Some fruit have kedusha whereas others don't? The question is in general about fruit that grew during shmita and may have been ripe but were only picked during year 8.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the OP is referring to kedushat shviit.

Comment: @Scimonster So am I....

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, if you feel that the question is based on a mistaken premise, feel free to answer correcting it. And if what fruit it is makes a difference, i think that's something for answerers to mention.

Comment: @Scimonster Certainly. If the OP is interested in Etrugim (as many are) then they should consider mentioning that explicitly and not relying on general fruit rules. This is something they may not have done (it being common around here for people to ask about general cases and then disappointed when their specific case is not addressed, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166155)) and hence something I'm glad to have assisted in pointing out.

Comment: Sometimes people ask a general question because they have no idea that specific cases within that generality vary.  Not everybody knows all the possible points of variation before asking a question.  Alice, if your question was motivated by particular fruits please edit that in; if you're happy with general answers, I hope such answers will point out that there are special cases.

Answer (score 2):

[Rambam Shmittah 4:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?&rid=7463) (translation from Chabad.org)

> וכן פירות שביעית שיצאו למוצאי שביעית בתבואה וקטניות ואילנות הולכין אחר עונת המעשרות. והפרגין והשומשמין והאורז והדוחן ופול המצרי שזרעו לזרע אחר גמר הפרי. והירק אחר לקיטתו:‏
>   Similarly, when the produce of the Sabbatical year is reaped in the eighth year: With regard to grain, legumes, and the fruit of the trees, [the ruling depends on when the produce reached] the stage when tithes are required to be separated. When rice, millet, poppy seeds, sesame seeds, and Egyptian beans are sown to produce seed, [the ruling depends on] when the produce completes its growth. [The ruling regarding] vegetables [depends] on the time they were harvested.

So it depends what kind of plant it is and (in some cases) how fully grown it was when the new year passed.

(This answer is not intended to address Etrugim.)

Comment: So if the fruit is ripe at around roshhashana of the 8th year, and you didn't have the chance to pick it but do so afterwards, the fruit maintains kedusha? Does that mean that if you have a field, you need to go and pick tons of fruit before the end of the year so that the new crop can be sold?

Comment: @alicefine As stated above, the kedusha status of the fruit depends what kind of plant it is and (in some cases) how fully grown it was when the new year passed. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: @alicefine to make it simple and give an example (and it would help if you would clarify what fruit you are asking about), if you have oranges in your garden which grew during a year of shmita, they retain their kedusha, you cannot sell them, can't throw them away, etc. Picking tons of fruit before year's end wouldn't help in any way as the fruit have *kdushat shviit* no matter what. The new crop (grown in the 8th year) can be sold as usual since it doesn't have *kdusha*.